# Onmouseover image with padding

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to add a padding to my `Onmouseover` image but nothing seems to work ... The raw code is

```
<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-white.png' width="40" height="40" onmouseover="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-green.png'; clicknovosti()" onmouseout="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-white.png';">
```

My apologies for being unclear, I am just trying to add the padding to the green version, to the hover image

Anyone might help ? Much appreciated

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: where is the padding code you've tried? have you tried `style="padding:50000px;"`?

Comment: I see nothing in the code you've posted related to padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-white.png' width="40" height="40" onmouseover="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-green.png'; this.style.padding='10px'" onmouseout="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/img-white.png';this.style.padding='0px'">
```

This will give padding.

Comment: thank you very much. i completely forgot the "this." in front of the style.